# How to check expiration date of crl file

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate, pki

I have a problem with certificate revocation list for ssl certificates.

How can I check expiration date of a crl file ?
How can I validate a crl file ?

Comment: Meanwhile I found solution:RTFM
man keytool

   -printcrl -file crl_ {-v}

          Reads the certificate revocation list (CRL) from the file crl_file.

          A Certificate Revocation List (CRL) is a list of digital certificates which have been revoked by the Certificate Authority (CA) that issued them. The CA generates crl_file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `crl` command from OpenSSL:

```
openssl crl -in file.crl -text
```

For more information see [the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/crl.html).

Comment: If I had more upvotes to give, I would.

Comment: If you're dealing with huge CRLs, do yourself a favor and run this with `| less`, because output will be *long*.

Comment: Tip: If your CRL file is actually in `.pem` (you can also check the contents of the file, if it says `BEGIN X509 CRL` then it's PEM). Then you should also pass the flag `-inform PEM`, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: for *DER*-formatted CRL files, use `-inform DER` ... for example: `openssl crl -inform DER -in derformattedfile.crl -text`